# Create Encrypted .sdf file in wp7/wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

```
public void createDB()
    {
        string strConnectionString = @"isostore:/accounts.sdf";
        using (dataContext accountdb = new dataContext(strConnectionString))
        {
            if (accountdb.DatabaseExists() == false)
            {
                accountdb.CreateDatabase();
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

    }
```

I've been trying to create an encrypted .sdf database file on wp8 without success, can anyone help me. The code above shows how to create .sdf file without encryption. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-ce ? `Encrypt Database=True;`

Comment: thanks for the reply Corak, another users gave me a code snippet that worked. And that site answered another question that i was going to ask. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, if you include a password in the connection string, the database file is automatically encrypted. Try this:

```
//string strConnectionString = @"isostore:/accounts.sdf";
strConnectionString = string.Format(@"Data Source = 'isostore:/accounts.sdf'; Password = '{0}';", globalPass);
```

Comment: Update-After more some toying around, the above code throws an exception because the keyword isostore wasn't apart of the string. <code>strConnectionString = string.Format(@"Data Source = 'isostore:/accounts.sdf'; Password = '{0}';", globalPass);</code>